# Obter o nome da Variável pela qual a função ou classe foi chamada

Tags: python

Estava olhando como são criados os bancos de dados no SQLAlchemy e fiquei em duvida na parte aonde crio variáveis de classes e são convertidos para uma coluna no banco de dado com o nome da variável usada.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite+pysqlite:///base.db'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(80), unique=True, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.username}>"
```

Como posso criar uma função que faz essa mesma coisa? que me retorne o nome da "Variável Original".
Ou que transforme o nome da "Variável Original" em uma Kwargs como acontecer na hora de salva algo no banco de dados.

```
db.session.add(User(username="Something"))
db.session.commit()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Não é possível para variáveis comuns quando chamam uma função (ok, até "é possível", mas é muito mais complicado, e não é a intenção de que algo assim seja feito).

Mas para nomes de atributos de classe - como é o caso aí, isso é possível sim - a questão é que ou a classe tem que ter uma metaclasse especial, ou o conteúdo do atributo de classe na decoração tem que ser um objeto que atenda ao protocolo de descritors (descriptor protocol) e tenha um método `__set_name__`.

Então, para ilustrar bem - isto é possível:

```
class MinhaClasse:
    meu_atributo = ClasseEspecial()

m = MinhaClasse()
print(m.nome)
out-> 'meu_atributo'
```

E isso não é possível (naquelas - "dá", mas não faça:):

```
def minha_funcao():
    minha_variavel = funcao_especial()
    print (minha_variavel.nome)

minha_funcao()
out-> 'minha_variavel'  # (Não tem como acontecer, a não ser com um hack muito grande)
```

Então, focando no que funciona e as pessoas são encorajadas a usar: se o seu atributo de classe for um objeto com um método `__get__`, ele é um descritor (um descriptor) - e o Python usa vários mecanismos legais com ele, inclusive podendo determinar o nome automaticamente:
No momento em que a classe é criada, o Python verifica todos os membros da classe que são descritores, e, se eles tiverem o método `__set_name__`, ele é chamado com dois parâmetros: a classe recém criada, e o próprio nome do membro, como uma string.

Ou seja, para o primeiro exemplo acima funcionar, pode-se usar algo assim:

```
class ClasseEspecial:
    def __get__(self, instance, owner):
        if instance is None: return self
        return instance.__dict__[self.name]
    def __set__(self, instance, value):
        instance.__dict__[self.name] = value
    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.name = name

class MinhaClasse:
    meu_atributo = ClasseEspecial()
```

E no modo interativo:

```
In [255]: MinhaClasse.meu_atributo.name                              
Out[255]: 'meu_atributo'
```

Por que isso funciona assim? Por que o *corpo* das classes é executado no momento em que um módulo é importado (em geral) - quando o bloco definido pelo comando `class` chega ao fim, o Python faz uma série de chamadas internas, que recebem como dados todas as variáveis definidas no corpo da classe (os atributos),  aí o mecanismo que descrevi acima entra em ação e o método `__set_name__` é chamado.

Já em uma função, o corpo delas só é executado quando elas são chamadas - as variáveis "não existem" até a função estar em execução,  e apesar dos mecanismos de introspecção do Python permitirem que o programa possa "ver" esses nomes de variável diretamente, isso não é recoemndado: o ideal é que nomes de variáveis sejam parte da estrutura do programa - se você precisa manipualr um nome de variável como dado (por exemplo, uma string), o melhor é usar um dicionário.  E também isso seria muito pouco útil - uma variável em uma função só é visível para o código dentro daquela própria função - ao contrário de um atributo de classe que pode ser consultado de qualquer lugar diretamente.

Só para deixar a resposta completa, vou descrever como uma função que é chamada poderia saber em qual variável vai ser armazenada - mas não vou dar um exemplo em código:

Existe um tipo de objeto que se chama "Frame" que mantém o estado de uma função em execução: ele tem como atributos o código que está sendo executado e as variáveis locais, e o frme da função "pai" - a função que chamou a função atual.
COm isso, uma função ao ser chamada pode:

1. obter o próprio frame de execução
2. do próprio frame, obter o frame da função onde ela foi chamada
3. nesse frame, obter o número da linha e ponto onde está a chamada a função (essa informação também está no frame)
4. obter o objeto de código (`__code__`): uma sequência de bytes representando o bytecode aquela função
5. olhar dentro do bytecode qual foi a instrução onde a função foi chamada
6. achar a partir dali as instruções que colocam o valor de retorno em uma variável local
7. obter, no objeto de código, o nome da variável a partir da sua posição

E, ao contrário do que acontece com atributos de classe, isso tudo vai funcionar por que a implementação de referência cPython faz dessa forma, e permite esses acessos - mas outras implementações de Python, como Pypy, Brython, etc.... não precisam (e não implementam) isso da mesma forma, então não dá para isso funcionar em qualquer variante da linguagem.